# Is there a way to change a range of the contents of a dataframe using data frame contents as an index?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a large dataframe that I wish to change values of one column in particular rows based on the value of another column which is not the index.

I can do it for a single instance, I want to be able to do it for a range of values.

```
import pandas as pd

INDEX = list(range(1, 11))
LOCATIONS = [3, 10, 6, 2, 9, 1, 7, 5, 8, 4]
DATA = [294, 143, 385, 110, 281, 157, 188, 501, 135, 186]
# Make dataframe
DF = pd.DataFrame(LOCATIONS, columns=['locStuff'], index = INDEX)
DF['data'] = pd.Series(DATA, index=INDEX)

# Location and new value inputs
LOC_TO_CHANGE = 8
NEW_LOC_VALUE = 9

# Changing the value in the dataframe
LOC_IND_TO_ADJUST = DF.index[DF['locStuff'] == LOC_TO_CHANGE].tolist()
LOC_IND_TO_ADJUST_INT = LOC_IND_TO_ADJUST[0]
DF.iloc[LOC_IND_TO_ADJUST_INT -1, 1] = ('%03d' % NEW_LOC_VALUE)
```

I would like to input locStuff[3:6] = data from another list I have whose length will be the same as the interval 3:6. I expect to change the contents of dataframe 'data' column for the positions in the locStuff column.

Comment: Can you explain more, what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need:

```
DF.iloc[3:6, 1] = ('%03d' % NEW_LOC_VALUE)
print (DF)
    locStuff data
1          3  294
2         10  143
3          6  385
4          2  009
5          9  009
6          1  009
7          7  188
8          5  501
9          8  135
10         4  186
```

Comment: Thank you jezrael, i couldn't find anything via google, still not sure what would have been the better search string to see this in documentation. Very much appreciated.